# Edit and Send back Image File User Uploads

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, file-upload, httpresponse

I'm building a front-end interface for a back-end image edited process (don't know all the correct jargon).

Basically:

- user should be able to upload an image file through the UI
- which sends it to the server
- where the image is edited in some way
- then the UI should display the edited image

I'm using an XHR request with the `POST` method as shown below to send the image file to the server.

```js
var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-button');

uploadButton.onclick = function() {
  
  this.innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
  
  //---------------
  var files = fileSelect.files
  var formData = new FormData();
  var file = files[0]
  
  if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
      formData.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
  }
  
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', true);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Upload';
    }
    else {
      alert('An error occurred!');
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
}; //end on-click 'Upload'
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-select" name="photos[]"/>

<button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
```

***My question is***: In general, once the image file is sent to the server, by the code above, **when/how does the edited image get sent back**?

- Will it be sent back as part of the server response to my `POST` request, and thus accessible in my `processRequest` callback function (assuming the server is configured to process it that way)?
- Do I have to send a `GET` request to get the edited file?

*I do not have access to the server/back-end at this point in time, and just know how the UI is supposed to work.*

Comment: It really depends. It should be returned after your POST request. Now, it could be done as the body of the request (ie. base64 encoding of a JPG or PNG picture) or only as a link to the newly hosted file on the server (in that scenario probably with a JSON response). Has the file got to be served by the server again after being returned the first time? If yes, second option is more plausible.

Comment: Ok. No, the file doesn't have to be served again after the first time. When you say, "the body of the request", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Using plain XHR, the request's response would be available through properties such as xhr.response and xhr.responseText, as stated in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest Hope it helps! :)

Comment: And, just to be super clear, those properties would be available inside your onload function :)

Comment: Ah, ok. I wasn't sure if the "body" was something other than what's found in xhr.response. Than you Marc!

Comment: My pleasure! :)